# How to use Peewee to make CASE SQL queries?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, peewee

I have a table in postgres that holds a priority integer for each row.
The priority needs to update whenever I add a new row or change the priority of an existing one for all of the other rows in the table.

One way to do it in pure SQL would be with a CASE query:

```
# example of editing priority 5 to 2 and fixing the rest
set Priority = case when Priority = 5 then 2
                    when Priority > 1 then Priority + 1
                    else Priority
               end
```

**Question: How can I use the peewee ORM in python to facilitate this query?**

I couldn't find a way to do it in the documentation. Although the documentation offers some great examples, my use case doesn't fit any one of the examples.

Comment: So you want to update **all** the records if **a single** record is changed? Use a spreadsheet!

Comment: When it's a table that's specifically required to keep records by priority and the number of records is insignificant - yes, I want to update **all** 12 records if two records are changed.

Comment: Read the docs bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `peewee.Case` (docs: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Case ). It is **well documented**.

```
class Task(Model):
    priority = IntegerField()

q = Task.update(priority=Case(None, (
    (Task.priority == 5, 2),
    (Task.priority > 1, Task.priority + 1)),
    Task.priority)
q.execute()
```